# Remove CR/LF from text field

Tags: c#, excel-interop

I have a problem, that when I retrieve a a txt file from column, with :

```
scanObject = scanWorksheet.Cells[i, scanCols[j]]; 

scanRange = (Excel.Range)scanObject;

scanRangeValue = scanRange.Value2;
```

it passes on Line Feed, LF, commands. From that I generate a textfile, to use as a input in another program, but this LF commands makes the import system skip the field. How do I remove them when retrieving the text column?

Comment: Replace them with nothing?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0):

In steps so you can see what each does:

```
// get the value in the cell (which is an object from Value2)
object scanRangeValue = scanRange.Value2;
// cast to string (you may need to check for errors if it is not a string)
string scanStringValue = (string)scanRangeValue;
// Replace both \r\n and \r and \n
scanStringValue = scanStringValue.Replace("\r", "").Replace("\n", "");
```

Note [`Value2`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.range.value2%28v=office.14%29.aspx) is an object type, so you need to cast to `string`. This may throw an exception if the value returned was not a `string`, so you may need to use `try ... catch ...` or other tests such as `if (scanRangeValue is string)` (see [MSDN - How to: Safely Cast by Using as and is Operators (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc488006.aspx))